# Using Discord API for c# without a bot

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I have an app, and I would like to store people's discord names for easy lookup, of course the names can change so I'm thinking of storing their IDs instead, but IDK how to turn an ID into their username and the other way around. Any ideas? I can't have a bot for reasons I won't get into.

This is for C# by the way, the functions I'm looking for are like

- GetUserID(string name)
- GetUsername(int id)

Edit: I am not using unity, and it appears the lib files in the official SDK are not usable by the dotnet framework? Or I have to import them in a different way? Or discord.net might be a better option?

The simpler the better, thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm assuming manually copying a user's Id right from the discord client isn't a solution.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah, plus I still need a way to get the username from the ID, which I assume will use some kind of API

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.